# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs

I am building CRUD app in ReactJs and trying to add, delete and fetch data from json file.

I am getting following error when I am trying to fetch data from `db.json` file

```
GET http://localhost:8080/cards 404 (Not Found)

"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "image": "http://placehold.it/400x300",
      "category": "CATEGORY 0",
      "placeholder": "Placeholder 0"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "image": "http://placehold.it/400x300",
      "category": "CATEGORY AAAA",
      "placeholder": "Placeholder BBB"

    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "image": "http://placehold.it/400x300",
      "category": "CATEGORY AAAA",
      "placeholder": "Placeholder BBB"

    }
  ]
}
```

**cardSaga.js**

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'

//
// fetch all cards
//
export function fetchCardsFromServer() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/cards')
    .then(response => response.json());
}

function* fetchCards() {
  try {
    const cards = yield call(fetchCardsFromServer);
    yield put({type: "FETCH_CARDS_SUCCEEDED", cards: cards});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: "FETCH_CARDS_FAILED", message: e.message});
  }
}

//
// add card
//
export function postCardToServer() {
  const card = {
    "image": "http://placehold.it/400x300",
    "category": "CATEGORY AAAA",
    "placeholder": "Placeholder BBB"
  }

  return fetch("http://localhost:8080/cards",{
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(card)
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}

function* addCard() {
  try {
    const card = yield call(postCardToServer);
    yield put({type: "ADD_CARD_SUCCEEDED", card: card});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: "ADD_CARD_FAILED", message: e.message});
  }
}

//
// remove card
//
export function removeCardAtServer(id) {
  return fetch("http://localhost:8080/cards" + id,{
      method: "DELETE"
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}

function* removeCard(action) {
  try {
    yield call(removeCardAtServer, action.id);
    yield put({type: "REMOVE_CARD_SUCCEEDED", index: action.id});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: "REMOVE_CARD_FAILED", message: e.message});
  }
}

function* cardSaga() {
  //fetch all
  yield takeLatest("FETCH_CARDS", fetchCards);
  //add
  yield takeLatest("ADD_CARD", addCard);
  //add
  yield takeLatest("REMOVE_CARD", removeCard);
}

export default cardSaga;
```

When I am trying to add cards to `db.json` file I'm getting following error

```
POST http://localhost:8080/cards 404 (Not Found)
"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
```

When I open my network tab and response in console all I see is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /cards</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm running my app on localhost:8080 and I am not sure why this is happening any tip and advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: most probably you are getting an html response, try opening the network tab and check the raw response

Comment: yes, I just see html code and Cannot GET /cards

Answer (score 1):

Your error is self-explained, 404 means that http://localhost:8080/cards is not available, so nothing to do with react here, check your application server response firstly.
you may use **postman** or any other tools to validate the rest response before proceeding with React implementation.

Here a customized example https://w7xr8.codesandbox.io

Comment: It is being saved to `db.json` file in my app not on server or database. So my `db.json` file is pretending to be server

Comment: The server cannot route to JSON element (card), that requires routing capabilities from the application server, you can use for example  http://localhost:8080/db.json instead, and then extract the card element from JSON file,what is your application server ?

Comment: How would I extract cards from `db.json`?

Comment: As per your case, you can use  response.cards directly

Comment: Can you please write it as code would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: sure here customized one https://w7xr8.codesandbox.io   by clicking the Axios button react will fetch data from the db.json file and extract the cards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196079/discussion-between-feras-and-user9347049).

Comment: Thanks for working example but can you post a code solution?